# Is it possible to access Grafana and Prometheus through reverse proxy using Nginx on same server

Tags: https, prometheus, grafana

Please is it possible to configure reverse proxy using nginx for Grafana and Prometheus on same server. I have configured Prometheus access through https(listening on port 443 and direct output to port 9090). This works fine but configuring Grafana which is on same server to be accessed through https has been impossible. I tried it listening on port 80 and direct its output to port 3000, but it always default to http port. I also tried another port for listening but never worked.
Has anyone done this before and please can you share your valuable experience. Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow [the procedure in grafana](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1) ? There is a bit of tinkering in grafana to get the urls right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this docker compose can be helpful https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/README.md

The suggestion is to move the ssl termination to any web server (NGinx, Traefik, HAProxy) and forward the request in plain text to the underline services (prometheus and grafana). Here some examples: [HAProxy exposes prometheus](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-exposes-a-prometheus-metrics-endpoint/) and [Traefik](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/blob/master/docker-traefik-stack.yml)

Comment: Thanks for sending the link, I am able to access Grafana and Prometheus via http at the moment but I want to make the access secure via https. I have been able to get Prometheus done but configuring for Grafana has not been possible on same server. This is the issue I have and looking for a way round it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself well, I edit the answer to make it better.

Comment: Thanks for sending the link, I will have a look.